# Why does this line work in my Chrome console, but not in Node.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm running Node v12.8.0

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (LAST_ID = 54)) + (FIRST_ID = 1);
```

This works in my chrome console, but in node, the error is

```
ReferenceError: LAST_ID is not defined
```

How can I get this to work cleanly in node, as I find it makes the code much more readable

Comment: Why do you want to *set* `LAST_ID` and `FIRST_ID` at the same time you use them instead of having these separately?

Comment: I am runing node 10 and this line of code works

Comment: Also why does multiplication with assignment makes code more readable?

Comment: If you want readability, then assign variables in their own statements. I didn't even notice that there were assignments there at first glance.

Comment: Have you got `"use strict";` in your node code? `"use strict";Math.floor(Math.random() * (LAST_ID = 54)) + (FIRST_ID = 1);` won't work in Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a module (Which is what node.js files are by default), [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is on automatically without `'use strict'`. In strict mode, if a variable is not defined, a `ReferenceError` is thrown. In sloppy mode, it is silently added to the global object.

You should define a variable instead of assigning to a global:

```js
let LAST_ID, FIRST_ID;
Math.floor(Math.random() * (LAST_ID = 54)) + (FIRST_ID = 1);
```